# Python sockets objects

Tags: python, sockets

Consider the following example.

```
from socket import *

msg = input("Please enter your name ")
msg = msg.encode()
myHostIp = ''
myHostPort = 54040

socket_obj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
socket_obj.bind((myHostIp,myHostPort))
socket_obj.listen(5)

while True:
    connection,address = socket_obj.accept()
    print("Client : ",address)
    connection.send(msg)
    print(socket.getsockname(socket_obj))
    print(socket.getsockname(connection))
    print(socket.getpeername(socket_obj))
    print(socket.getpeername(connection))
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(1024)
        print("This was received from ", data)
    connection.close()
```

In this simple program the output of line `print(socket.getsockname(socket_obj))` was `(0.0.0.0)`
and of the `print(socket.getpeername(socket_obj))` was `socket_obj is not connected.`

My question is: once `connection,address = socket_obj.accept()` is executed, is the control from `socket_obj` transferred to `connection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket you call `.listen()` on is a *server socket*; about all you can do with it is to call `.accept()` to produce a *client socket*, which handles all actual communications.  One server socket can produce any number of client sockets over its lifetime.